# JSON request is empty

Tags: angularjs

I need to send a data to the server and get back a json array object.

But with the below code, JSON request which is sent to server is empty.

Menu.js

```
var app = angular.module('Menu', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);

app.controller("MenuController", ["$scope", "$resource",
  function($scope, $resource) {
    //Resource config of my server
    var userModules = $resource("/api/modules", {}, {
      'save': {
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: true
      }
    });

    //passing this user id to get a json response
    userModules.Userid = "pals";
    $scope.pamodules = "";


    //call to my server to get a json response
    userModules.save(function(result, putResponseHeaders) {
      $scope.pamodules = result;
      sessionStorage["pamodules"] = JSON.stringify(result);
      alert(sessionStorage["pamodules"]);
    });
  }
]);
```

index.html

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key,item) in pamodules">
    {{item}} -- {{item.Module}} -- {{item.Link}}
  </div>
```

Do let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly are you trying to `save` here?

Comment: am trying to get a json response from server in the format [{"Module":"A","Link":"A/B"},{"Module":"B","Link":"B/C"}] and save it